# Resizable Form with Border set to None by top "Panel" object with Dock property set to Top

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, resize

I want to make a simple C# (VS) pop-up window for my project in python, I want to use VS due to aesthetics.

(Please keep in mind that I am C# newbie)

**What have I already done**

So I created the project, set `Border` property of the main form to `None` and added the Panel object which I called `titleBarPanel`.
I have already enabled the resizing of the form by the Bottom and Sides of the form and enabled dragging of the form by the `titleBarPanel`.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to simply enable the form to be resizable by the top panel object.

**What have I tried**

I have searched through stackoverflow asd well as on youtube but I couldn't find anything.
I also tried asking ChatGPT but well he was not that smart in that case and couldn't resolve my problem.

**The code**
Due to small volume of the code I will give the entire code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UI_Variables_Prompt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
        private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
        private const int HTBOTTOMLEFT = 0x10;
        private const int HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 0x11;
        private const int HTLEFT = 0xa;
        private const int HTRIGHT = 0xb;
        private const int HTBOTTOM = 0xf;
        private const int HTTOP = 0xc;
        private const int HTTOPLEFT = 0xd;
        private const int HTTOPRIGHT = 0xe;


        private bool isDragging = false;
        private Point dragStart;
        private bool isResizing = false;
        private int resizeDir = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            titleBarPanel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(titleBarPanel_MouseDown);
            titleBarPanel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(titleBarPanel_MouseMove);
            titleBarPanel.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(titleBarPanel_MouseUp);
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
            this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseUp);

        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
            const int HTCLIENT = 1;
            const int HTCAPTION = 2;
            const int HTTOP = 12;
            const int HTLEFT = 10;
            const int HTRIGHT = 11;
            const int HTBOTTOM = 15;
            const int HTTOPLEFT = 13;
            const int HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
            const int HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
            const int HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (m.Result == (IntPtr)HTCLIENT)
                {
                    Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
                    pos = this.PointToClient(pos);
                    if (pos.Y < 10)
                    {
                        if (pos.X < 10)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
                        else if (pos.X > this.ClientSize.Width - 10)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
                    }
                    else if (pos.Y > this.ClientSize.Height - 10)
                    {
                        if (pos.X < 10)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                        else if (pos.X > this.ClientSize.Width - 10)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
                    }
                    else if (pos.X < 10)
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
                    else if (pos.X > this.ClientSize.Width - 10)
                        m.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
                }
                else if (m.Result == (IntPtr)HTCAPTION)
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCLIENT;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }

        private int ResizeDirection(Point cursorPos, Rectangle formBounds)
        {
            const int HTLEFT = 10;
            const int HTRIGHT = 11;
            const int HTTOP = 12;
            const int HTTOPLEFT = 13;
            const int HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
            const int HTBOTTOM = 15;
            const int HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
            const int HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

            if (cursorPos.Y < formBounds.Top + 10)
            {
                if (cursorPos.X < formBounds.Left + 10)
                    return HTTOPLEFT;
                else if (cursorPos.X > formBounds.Right - 10)
                    return HTTOPRIGHT;
                else
                    return HTTOP;
            }
            else if (cursorPos.Y > formBounds.Bottom - 10)
            {
                if (cursorPos.X < formBounds.Left + 10)
                    return HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                else if (cursorPos.X > formBounds.Right - 10)
                    return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                else
                    return HTBOTTOM;
            }
            else if (cursorPos.X < formBounds.Left + 10)
                return HTLEFT;
            else if (cursorPos.X > formBounds.Right - 10)
                return HTRIGHT;

            return 0;
        }


        private void titleBarPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                isDragging = true;
                dragStart = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }
        }

        private void titleBarPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isDragging)
            {
                Point p = PointToScreen(e.Location);
                Location = new Point(p.X - this.dragStart.X, p.Y - this.dragStart.Y);
            }
            else if (isResizing)
            {
                switch (resizeDir)
                {
                    case HTTOP:
                        this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, this.dragStart.Y - e.Y + this.Height);
                        break;
                    case HTTOPLEFT:
                        this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, this.dragStart.X - e.X + this.Width);
                        this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, this.dragStart.Y - e.Y + this.Height);
                        this.Left = Math.Min(this.Left + e.X - this.dragStart.X, this.Left + this.Width - this.MinimumSize.Width);
                        break;
                    case HTTOPRIGHT:
                        this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, e.X - this.dragStart.X + this.Width);
                        this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, this.dragStart.Y - e.Y + this.Height);
                        break;
                    case HTLEFT:
                        this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, this.dragStart.X - e.X + this.Width);
                        this.Left = Math.Min(this.Left + e.X - this.dragStart.X, this.Left + this.Width - this.MinimumSize.Width);
                        break;
                    case HTRIGHT:
                        this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, e.X - this.dragStart.X + this.Width);
                        break;
                    case HTBOTTOM:
                        this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, e.Y - this.dragStart.Y + this.Height);
                        break;
                    case HTBOTTOMLEFT:
                        this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, this.dragStart.X - e.X + this.Width);
                        this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, e.Y - this.dragStart.Y + this.Height);
                        this.Left = Math.Min(this.Left + e.X - this.dragStart.X, this.Left + this.Width - this.MinimumSize.Width);
                        break;
                    case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
                        this.Width = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Width, e.X - this.dragStart.X + this.Width);
                        this.Height = Math.Max(this.MinimumSize.Height, e.Y - this.dragStart.Y + this.Height);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void titleBarPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            isResizing = false;
            resizeDir = 0;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isResizing = false;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !isDragging)
            {
                this.dragStart = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                isResizing = true;
                resizeDir = ResizeDirection(e.Location, this.Bounds);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isResizing)
            {
                int cursorType = 0;
                switch (resizeDir)
                {
                    case HTTOP:
                    case HTBOTTOM:
                        cursorType = Cursors.SizeNS.Handle.ToInt32();
                        break;
                    case HTLEFT:
                    case HTRIGHT:
                        cursorType = Cursors.SizeWE.Handle.ToInt32();
                        break;
                    case HTTOPLEFT:
                    case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
                        cursorType = Cursors.SizeNWSE.Handle.ToInt32();
                        break;
                    case HTTOPRIGHT:
                    case HTBOTTOMLEFT:
                        cursorType = Cursors.SizeNESW.Handle.ToInt32();
                        break;
                }

                Cursor.Current = new Cursor(new IntPtr(cursorType));
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: This is how the form looks like, no tricky business]

Thank You very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title-bar `Panel` is the problem here which receives the mouse inputs and not the `From`. As a result, the Form's move and resize routines do not work in the panel's region which makes you replicate almost the same code to handle the panel's mouse inputs separately.

Well, you don't need to do that, a simple alternative is to subclass the panel's native window to make it *transparent* to the mouse inputs and relay them to the parent to process. Do the same for the panel's non-click child controls if any (i.e. a `PictureBox` that shows the Icon and a `Label` that displays the caption/title...).

To subclass, pass a `Control` to a derived class from `NativeWindow`, assign its handle and override the `WndProc` method to trap the `WM_NCHITTEST` messages and assign the `HTTRANSPARENT` pointer to the `Result` property.

An example here for a borderless `Form` that contains a `Panel` docked to the top. The `Panel` itself hosts a `PictureBox` that displays an image and a `Label` to display the title.

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

//Within your namespace...

public partial class BorderlessForm : Form
{        
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    const int HTCAPTION = 2;
    const int HTLEFT = 10;
    const int HTRIGHT = 11;
    const int HTTOP = 12;
    const int HTTOPLEFT = 13;
    const int HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
    const int HTBOTTOM = 15;
    const int HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
    const int HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;
    const int gripSize = 10;

    public BorderlessForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new NcHitTestTransparentControl(pnlTitle);
        new NcHitTestTransparentControl(picImage);
        new NcHitTestTransparentControl(lblTitle);

        SetMaxSize();

        SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += (s, e) => SetMaxSize();            
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x20000; // WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            var pt = PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
            var cs = ClientSize;

            if (pt.X >= cs.Width - gripSize && pt.Y >= cs.Height - gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.X <= gripSize && pt.Y >= cs.Height - gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.X <= gripSize && pt.Y <= gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.X >= cs.Width - gripSize && pt.Y <= gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.Y <= gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.Y >= cs.Height - gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.X <= gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
                return;
            }
            if (pt.X >= cs.Width - gripSize)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
                return;
            }

            var r = new Rectangle(gripSize, gripSize, 
                Width - gripSize * 2, pnlTitle.Height);

            // Remove this condition if you want to move the Form
            // from any point.
            if (r.Contains(pt))
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
                return;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private void SetMaxSize()
    {
        MaximumSize = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Size;
    }

    private class NcHitTestTransparentControl : NativeWindow
    {
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        const int HTTRANSPARENT = -1;

        internal NcHitTestTransparentControl(Control ctrl)
        {
            if (ctrl.Handle != IntPtr.Zero) AssignHandle(ctrl.Handle);
            ctrl.HandleCreated += (s, e) => AssignHandle(ctrl.Handle);
            ctrl.HandleDestroyed += (s, e) => ReleaseHandle();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
                m.Result = new IntPtr(HTTRANSPARENT);
            else
                base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }       
}
```

**Notes**

- Overriding the `CreateParams` property to add the `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` style is necessary to minimize and restore a borderless `Form` when you click its taskbar icon.
- Calling the `SetMaxSize` method to set the Form's `MaximumSize` is to not cover the taskbar area when you maximize the Form.
- You shouldn't ignore the designer's warning message and you shouldn't scale the display of the development environment. 100% display to design your forms and lay out your controls. Make sure that your app is [DpiAware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).
- Avoid repositioning and resizing a `Form` by setting the corresponding properties (`Location` and `Size`). Doing so sends continuous redraw requests as you move or resize the `Form`. Favor the native approach as shown or through p/invoke the relevant functions to *swallow* some redraw callers.
- You don't need to re-declare local fields/constants when you already have them declared as class fields/constants.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you wish to drag the mouse on the `titleBarPanel` and have that resize the form (instead of the normal behavior of *moving* the form). To achieve this, consider implementing [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter) to hook the mouse events regardless of which control (e.g. `titleBarPanel`) is focused for the click. Now all you have to do is:

- Determine whether mouse position is in the `titleBarPanel` rectangle
- If so, capture the mouse down `Size` and `Location`
- As the mouse moves, recalc the main form `Size` based on how much the mouse has moved.

*Don't forget to [Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.capture) the mouse!*

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    private Point _dragStartScreen;
    private Size _dragStartSize;
    private bool _dragResizing = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        MinimumSize = new Size(50, 50); // Make sure it can't disappear!
    }
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201; 
    const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                var client = PointToClient(MousePosition);
                if (titleBarPanel.ClientRectangle.Contains(client))
                {
                    _dragResizing = true;
                    _dragStartScreen = MousePosition;
                    _dragStartSize = Size;
                    Capture = true;
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (_dragResizing)
                {
                    int
                        deltaX = MousePosition.X - _dragStartScreen.X,
                        deltaY = MousePosition.Y - _dragStartScreen.Y;
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Size = new Size(_dragStartSize.Width + deltaX, _dragStartSize.Height + deltaY);
                    }));
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                _dragResizing = false;
                Capture = false;
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

The code snippet above addresses:

> **What I want to achieve** - I want to simply enable the form to be resizable by the top panel object.

The full code that I used to test this answer puts resize-move icons on the title bar.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/resize-form-by-title-bar.git) demo code.

Comment: A good working example. However, personally, I would prefer to let Windows handle the dragging of the window natively.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, it should be that the dragging and resizing state is not well handled and the dragging is too laggy.

I re-wrote the code, you can refer to it, before you need to adjust the dock property of the panel to Top. Please slow down when you drag, otherwise you will not be able to tell whether it is moving or resizing. If you want to fix this bug, you can change all -10 to -20 or larger in panel1_MouseMove, but this will not be very beautiful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PanelResize1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool isMouseDown = false;  // Indicates whether the mouse is currently pressed, the initial value is No

        MouseDirection direction = MouseDirection.None; //Indicates the direction of dragging, starting with None, indicating no dragging

        private Point mPoint; //mouse coordinates

        private bool state = true; // Whether to change the size of the form, true is not, false is yes

        public enum MouseDirection  //Define an enumeration to indicate the dragging direction
        {
            Herizontal,  
            Vertical,
            Declining,
            None
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            isMouseDown = true;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //When the mouse is moving, the coordinates are changing all the time
            //When the mouse moves, the abscissa is within 10 pixels from the right edge of the window and the ordinate is within 10 pixels from the bottom edge, the cursor should be changed into an oblique arrow shape, and the dragging direction should be set to MouseDirection.Declining
            if (e.Location.X >= this.Width - 10 && e.Location.Y > panel1.Height - 10)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                direction = MouseDirection.Declining;
                state = false;
            }
            else if (e.Location.X >= this.Width - 10)
            //When the abscissa is within 10 pixels from the right edge of the window when the mouse moves, the cursor should be changed into an oblique arrow shape, and the dragging direction should be set to MouseDirection.Herizontal else if (e.Location.X >= this. Width - 10)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                direction = MouseDirection.Herizontal;
                state = false;
            }
            else if (e.Location.Y > this.Height - 10)
            //Similarly, when the ordinate is within 10 pixels from the bottom edge of the form when the mouse moves, the cursor should be changed into an oblique arrow shape, and the dragging direction should be set to MouseDirection.Vertical else if (e.Location.Y >= this .Height - 10)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                direction = MouseDirection.Vertical;
                state = false;
            }
            else if(e.Location.X >= panel1.Width-10 )
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                direction = MouseDirection.Herizontal;
                state = false;
            }
            else if ( e.Location.Y > panel1.Height - 10)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                direction = MouseDirection.Vertical;
                state = false;
            }
            else
            //Otherwise, the mouse constellations are all one-way arrows in other window areas (default) else
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                state = true;
            }
            // After setting the direction, call the following method to change the size of the window
            if (state)
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                    this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + e.X - mPoint.X, this.Location.Y + e.Y - mPoint.Y);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ResizeWindow();
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = false;
            direction = MouseDirection.None;
        }

        private void ResizeWindow()
        {
            if (!isMouseDown)
                return;
            if (direction == MouseDirection.Declining)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                this.Width = MousePosition.X - this.Left;
                this.Height = MousePosition.Y - panel1.Top;
                panel1.Height = MousePosition.Y - this.Top;
            }
            if (direction == MouseDirection.Herizontal)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                this.Width = MousePosition.X - this.Left;
            }
            else if (direction == MouseDirection.Vertical)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                this.Height = MousePosition.Y - panel1.Top;
                panel1.Height = MousePosition.Y - this.Top;
            }
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```