# c# winform form resize with FormBorderStyle none

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

It allows to resize a form by default when FormBorderStyle=Sizable. But in that case the ugly top bar is shown. I need to hide the top bar but to allow the form to be resized. Any trick of doing that?

I need to allow the user to resize the form
[image: A form with FormBorderStyle=None. But the form can be resized by the user]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75918073/14171304

Answer (score 0):

Clear the `Text` property of the form and set the `ControlBox` property to `false`. That will retain the draggable border, assuming that `FormBorderStyle` enables it, but remove the title bar.